# Electron - How do you revoke session permissions?

Tags: javascript, session, permissions, electron

In my Electron application, I am able to deny or allow a `<webview>`'s request to use the microphone as shown here:
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#4-handle-session-permission-requests-from-remote-content

However I don't see a way to revoke a permission once it's granted without calling `webview.reload()` (which works but isn't optimal).

I allow a permission using

```
session
  .fromPartition('persist:example')
  .setPermissionRequestHandler((webContents, permission, callback) => {
    const url = webContents.getURL()

    if (permission === 'media') {
      // Approves the permissions request
      callback(true)
    }

    // Verify URL
    if (!url.startsWith('https://example.com/')) {
      // Denies the permissions request
      return callback(false)
    }
  })
```

Setting permission request handler to null also does not seem to revoke permissions that have already been approved.

```
setPermissionRequestHandler(null)
```

Comment: this may be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/remove

Comment: Where do you put the above code to register a custom handler for session permissions, the docs do not explain where?